# vue отправка формы без button и input

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Имеется форма и нужно её отправить без button и input использую (a). Почему без? Ломаются стили...
Пример:

Форма и кнопка:

```
<form @submit.prevent="send">
     ...
<a>Отправить</a>
</form>
```

(send - метод, где я использую axios)

Знаю, что можно использовать @click и отправить все нужные поля, но тогда не работает банальная валидация в форме (reqired и тд) + тогда и сама форма не нужна.

Пробовал способ от сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996657/submit-a-form-in-vue-how-do-i-reference-the-form-element но он просто отправляет форму как нативном html

Comment: Если нужна валидация формы, можно использовать checkValidity

Comment: Ну стили поправить можно то. Не зря же в форме придумали 2 кнопки отправки

Comment: Может тебе это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340300/a-tag-as-a-submit-button

Comment: Проблему как раз решил исправлением стилей

Comment: https://habr.com/post/317728/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, сделай так.

...
Отправить

methods: {
  send() {
  form.submit()
}
}